# Ordinals in $L$, the constructible universe

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, ordinals, descriptive-set-theory

I am trying to understand the constructible universe $L$. Based on the way it is constructed, it is clear that every ordinal is included in $L$, i.e., $\alpha \subset L$ for any ordinal $\alpha$. However, it is not clear to me whether $\alpha \in L$ or not for an arbitrary ordinal $\alpha$. In Jech's book *Set Theory*, the author says "$L$ is an inner model of ZF and contains all ordinals..." (these are not his exact words but same idea). Does the word contain in the previous sentence mean include or for any ordinal $\alpha$ we have $\alpha \in L$?

Any help will be greatly appreciated it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm confused here, but if $L$ contains $\alpha+1 = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}$ as a subset, won't that mean that it contains $\alpha$ as an element?

Comment: Yes, but not all ordinals $\beta$ can be expressed in the form $\beta = \alpha + 1$ for some other ordinal $\alpha$, right?

Comment: For this "trick" to work, you don't need $\alpha$ to be a successor ordinal, you just need it to have a successor ordinal, which all ordinals do.

Comment: But you want the other direction, that every ordinal has a successor, which is true. The point that @ElchananSolomon is making (and which I also make in my answer below) is that as soon as $L$ has $\alpha+1$ as a subset then it has $\alpha$ as an element.

Comment: If you’ve shown that for all ordinals $\alpha$, we have $\alpha \subseteq L$, then just note that for any ordinal $\alpha$, we have $S(\alpha) \subseteq L$ and thus $\alpha \in L$.

Comment: yes, I just realize it was a mistake.

Comment: "$L$ contains all ordinals" means "$On \subset L$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $L$ contains all the ordinals as elements. In fact this follows from what you already know (that $L$ contains all the ordinals as subsets): since smaller ordinals are elements of larger ordinals, for every class $X$ and ordinal $\alpha$ we have that if $\alpha+1\subseteq X$ then $\alpha\in X$. So the "ambiguity" around the notion of containment here, isn't.

A bit more explicitly, you can show by transfinite induction that $\alpha\in L_{\alpha+1}\setminus L_\alpha$ for each ordinal $\alpha$. So this tells us exactly when each ordinal appears in $L$. Note that this exactly matches the behavior of the $V$-hierarchy: in general $L_\alpha$ is always "as tall as" $V_\alpha$ but usually much "narrower" (even if $V=L$ - note that $L_\alpha$ is countable whenever $\alpha$ is countable, while $V_{\omega+1}$ already has size continuum).

Comment: Does this mean that it does not make any sense to consider $L[2^\omega]$ given that $2^\omega \in L$?

Comment: @BobVance First of all, it's not provable from $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone that $2^\omega\in L$. That said however we always will have that $L[2^\omega]$ is "trivial" (i.e. just $L$ itself) since *being an element of* $2^\omega$ (= being a subset of $\omega$) is definable over $L$ already. $L[A]$ is different from $L$ when "$A$-ness," even of things *in* $L$, is hard to detect (= not definable in $L$). So even if $2^\omega\not\in L$ we have $L[2^\omega]=L$. Note that there's a difference between $L[A]$ and $L(A)$ - in particular, if $2^\omega\not\in L$ then $L(2^{\omega})\not=L$.

Comment: For an extreme(ly important) example of this, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "If there are fairly big large cardinals (I'm keeping this vague for simplicity) then [the axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) holds in $L(2^\omega)$, but $\mathsf{AD}$ unconditionally fails in $L=L[2^\omega]$."

Comment: I am confused. In my mind (and most likely I'm wrong) $2^{\omega} \in L[2^{\omega}]$ but you just said that $L[2^{\omega}] = L$.

Comment: @BobVance It is not generally true that $A\in L[A]$ (by contrast, $A\in L(A)$ is always true). In particular, $2^\omega\not\in L[2^\omega]$ if there is a nonconstructible real (= if $2^\omega$ is not in $L$ already).

Comment: But if $A$ is an ordinal, we have that $A \in L[A]$, right?

Comment: @BobVance If $A$ is an ordinal then $A\in L$ already so of course $A\in L[A]$. If $A$ is a **set of** ordinals, or more generally any subset of $L$, then $A\in L[A]$ even if $L\not=L[A]$. (Meanwhile if $A$ is a sub*class* of $L$ then $A\cap V_\alpha\in L[A]$ for each ordinal $\alpha$.) But $2^\omega$ is a set *of sets of* ordinals, and things aren't so nice at that point.